# In Mongoengine can you query for string that is not contained in any element of a list?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have documents in Mongo of the form:

```
{
   type : '1234_CAKE'
},
{
   type : '1234_BEEF_63'
},
{
   type : '1234_CAKE'
},
{
   type : '1234_HAM_234'
},
{
   type : '1234_NAARTJIE'
}
```

I'd like to query all documents that don't have `CAKE` or `BEEF` somewhere in the type.

I've tried

```
Food.objects(type_not__icontains='cake')
```

which works to omit cakes or any other single type, but I don't know to extend it to multiple

```
Food.objects(type_not__icontains=['cake', 'beef'])
```

Throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator in mongodb, which return all the documents where the given fields are either not present or doesn't exist. E.g.

```
Food.objects(type__nin=['cake', 'beef'])
```

In order to make it case-insensitive you can use `$regex`  however it will not be efficient once your `Food` collection will have large number of records because non-rooted regular expressions don't utilize indexes even if they do exists. A better solution is just to denormalize your data to store lower-case version of type field and use it. For e.g

```
Food.objects(newlowercasetype__nin=['cake', 'beef'])
```

Comment: That only matches the whole field, notice that type is has numbers and underscores too. Also $nin is case sensitive isn't it.

Comment: Even denormalizing will not resolve this. Please look at the type field in my documents. For example `1234_BEEF` converted to lowercase `1234_beef` would still not be found by type `newlowercasetype__nin=['cake', 'beef'`]` because of the 1234_ prefix.

Comment: You can store only relevant part during denormalization . Can't you?

Comment: Yes I guess so, I guess that is my best option.